# Why is Web API Authentication not working?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Here I'm using Web API Authentication to check user credentials against my database. I wrote a condition in my Repo.cs file:

```
public bool EmailValidation(string UserName, string password)
{
    var x = (from n in db.LoginCrediential
        where n.UserName == UserName && n.Password == password
        select n);
    if (x != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I have a class file with name  `MyAuthorizationServerProvider`. When I enter credentials against my db it accepts my details, but why is it not moving inside my if condition?

```
public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider: OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    ICrendentials objcredential = new Crendentials();
    LoginCrediential objUser = new LoginCrediential();

    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated(); // 
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);

        if (context.UserName == objUser.UserName && context.Password == objUser.Password)
        {
            var x = objcredential.EmailValidation(context.UserName, context.Password);
            if (x==true)
            {

            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **You** need to debug your code to figure that out *but* if I had to guess: you can't/should not store passwords as plain text. The persisted password is *probably* the hashed value. If I am wrong on my guess and you are storing passwords in plain text then you need to change your code and not do that.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line "if (context.UserName == objUser.UserName && context.Password == objUser.Password)"? objUser = new LoginCrediential(), so that will never match. Remove the line and check the credentials in EmailValidation. But not sure why it is called 'EmailValidation'. Also don't forget to set the error if x==false. And just in case, use encrypted passwords.